# How many combinations are there of a list of $2000$ items, used $3$ times?

Tags: combinations

Suppose I have a list of $2000$ words and I want to combine them, randomly choosing a word from this list each time

e.g. Apple-Orange-Boat or Apple-Apple-Apple

How many possible combinations are there?

Is it simply $2000^3$?

Comment: It depends whether the order matters. For example, are you counting Apple-Orange-Boat and Orange-Apple-Boat as different things?

Comment: yes, different.. I'm using them as "fairly" unique human-readable identifiers, just like Stanley Carol and Carol Stanley would be different people, so too are these different.

Comment: In that case, since you are allowing repeats and the order matters the total number of combinations is $2000^3$. You have 2000 choices for the first word, 2000 for the second, and 2000 for the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you want a combination, then "Apple-Orange-Boat" is the same as "Orange-Boat-Apple". The order does not matter and therefore $2000^3$ is counting too much. For combination with repetitions, your answer is $$\begin{pmatrix}n+k-1\\k-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2000+3-1\\3-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2002\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Of course, if you *want* to consider the order, then you are not talking about combinations. In this case, the answer would be $2000^3$.

Comment: yes I did not mean the mathematical term "combinations", but the colloquial term - it has been many years since I studied any math

Answer (score 1):

**Without ordering** and **without repetitions**, eg Apple-Orange-Boat is the same as Orange-Apple-Boat and Orange-Orange-Orange is not allowed:

$$
{n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{2000!}{3!(2000-3)!} = 1.331334E9
$$

**Without ordering** and **with repetitions**, eg Apple-Orange-Boat is the same as Orange-Apple-Boat and Orange-Orange-Orange is allowed:

$$
{n+k-1 \choose k} = {n+k-1 \choose n-1} = \frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!} = \frac{(2000+3-1)!}{3!(2000-1)!} = 1.335334E9
$$

**With ordering** and **without repetitions**, eg Apple-Orange-Boat is different from Orange-Apple-Boat and Orange-Orange-Orange is not allowed:

$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{2000!}{(2000-3)!} = 7.988004E9
$$

**With ordering** and **with repetitions**, eg Apple-Orange-Boat is different from Orange-Apple-Boat and Orange-Orange-Orange is allowed:

$$
n^k = 2000^3 = 8E9
$$

So, based on your comments, your instinct was indeed correct.